# Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/dllName.dll' will not be loaded due to errors: | Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, entity-framework-core, package

Our project was running on Unity 2019.4.37f1. I'm trying to use an external DLL(.Net Standart 2.0) which has a reference to EntityFramework Core(3.1.25 version) with Unity and I get the following error in Unity Hub(I have tested it in a visual studio project and it works fine):

**Assembly 'Assets/dllName.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'.**

**Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.**

When I tried to remove EF Core reference from DLL and use it in Unity it works properly.

*Note:
You can reproduce the problem in any Unity project.*

I have been searching about this but had no luck finding the right solution. Any help is appreciated greatly.

[image: Unity Player Configuration]

[image: DLL dependencies]